# Having a list within a <dd> tag using Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

World!

I am trying to find a nice way to have multiple lines of information within a  tag. At the moment I have the following:

```
<dl class="row">
    <dt class="col-2">
        Role Name
    </dt>
    <dd class="col-10">
        Test Role
    </dd>

    <!-- IsActive -->
    <dt class="col-2">
        Active
    </dt>
    <dd class="col-10">
        <input checked="checked" class="check-box" disabled="disabled" type="checkbox">
    </dd>

    <!-- Groups -->
    <dt class="col-2">
        Groups
    </dt>
    <dd class="col-10">
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li class="list-group-item">testadgroup1</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">testadgroup2</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">testadgroup3</li>
        </ul>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

My first thought would be to use the list-group class along with list-group-flush with the following changes to the default CSS:

```
.list-group-item {
    padding-left: .625rem;
    padding-right: .625rem;
    padding-top: .375rem;
    padding-bottom: .375rem;
}

.list-group-item:first-of-type {
    padding-top: 0rem;
}
```

This works, but I feel like there must be a better way to achieve a similar behavior that I am not seeing.

Other notes in case it matters:

- I'm using Bootstrap 4, ASP.NET MVC
- I'm open to using external libraries so long as they play nicely with Bootstrap 4

```css
.list-group-item {
        padding-left: .625rem;
        padding-right: .625rem;
        padding-top: .375rem;
        padding-bottom: .375rem;
    }

    .list-group-item:first-of-type {
        padding-top: 0rem;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<dt class="col-2">
            Role Name
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-10">
            Test Role
        </dd>

        <!-- IsActive -->
        <dt class="col-2">
            Active
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-10">
            <input checked="checked" class="check-box" disabled="disabled" type="checkbox">
        </dd>

        <!-- Groups -->
        <dt class="col-2">
            Groups
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-10">
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <li class="list-group-item">testadgroup1</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">testadgroup2</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">testadgroup3</li>
            </ul>
        </dd>
    </dl>
```

Comment: you can nest bootstrap divs, so defining a <div class="row"> within the col-10 div, and then within that row div defining col divs to get the positioning you want

Answer (score 1):

Big thanks to [Marshall Tigerus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2134021/marshall-tigerus) for his comment on my original post.

With his tip I managed to get things looking quite nice without almost any overhead.

My new code:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<dl class="row">
    <!-- RoleName -->
    <dt class="col-2">
        Role Name
    </dt>
    <dd class="col-10">
        Test Role
    </dd>

    <!-- IsActive -->
    <dt class="col-2">
        Active
    </dt>
    <dd class="col-10">
        <input checked="checked" class="check-box" disabled="disabled" type="checkbox">
    </dd>

    <!-- Groups -->
    <dt class="col-2">
        Groups
    </dt>
    <dd class="col-10">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">testadgroup1</div>
            <div class="col-12">testadgroup2</div>
            <div class="col-12">testadgroup3</div>
        </div>
    </dd>
</dl>
```